# How to connect a storyboard to a .h and .m

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I have in an app a viewController without a .xib, because I want to use with that ViewController a storyboard instead. The problem is that I don't know how to tell Xcode that `ViewController2.storyboard` is the view of `ViewController2.h` and `ViewController2.m`. Anyone knows it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use storyboards, you generally instantiate the view controller inside the storyboard. The big advantage that storyboards have over .xibs is that they model not just the view hierarchy but also the flow from one view controller to the next. So, you'll probably want to either instantiate your view controller in the storyboard where you plan to use it, or else just go back to loading the view from a .xib (which isn't all that different anyway).

Comment: Ok, but how I instantiate my view controller in the storyboard?

Comment: Drag a view controller icon from the library into the storyboard. Then select the view controller and set it's type to your view controller Class.